# Splitting a value in a row to multiple column

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file whose first column contains track name and artist name and other info. I want to split the first column value into 2 different columns. sample of the csv file is below.

```
artist_trackname,year,month,day,hour,minute
'Sonic Species & Volcano - What Is Life\n',2020,8,5,0,25
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
artist,trackname,year,month,day,hour,minute
'Sonic Species & Volcano, What Is Life\n',2020,8,5,0,25
```

Can someone help me getting this done in python?

Comment: does the two values always separated by hyphen?

Comment: Are you using the [`csv module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) to process the file?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want an additional column based solely on the ' - ' portion of artist_trackname.

This can be easily done in Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
```

Load your csv:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"./filename.csv")

df.head()


artist_trackname    year    month   day hour    minute
0   'Sonic Species & Volcano - What Is Life\n'  2020    8   5   0   25
```

Split the item into two columns off of the ' - ':

```
df[['artist','trackname']] = df['artist_trackname'].str.split(" - ", n = 1, expand = True)
```

Drop the old column:

```
df.drop(columns=["artist_trackname"], inplace=True)
```

Reorder the columns to your intended format:

```
df[['artist','trackname','year','month','day','hour','minute']]

df.head()

    artist  trackname   year    month   day hour    minute
0   'Sonic Species & Volcano    What Is Life\n' 2020    8   5   0   25
```

Write back to csv:

```
df.to_csv(r"/path/to/filename.csv")
```

Comment: This one helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If these fields are always separated by a hyphen, you can just use the python terminal to read in the file, replace the " - " with a "," and you're done. Here is an example assuming your CSV file is named test.csv:

```
>>> with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
...     lines = f.readlines()
... 
>>> lines
['artist_trackname,year,month,day,hour,minute\n', "'Sonic Species & Volcano - What Is Life\\n',2020,8,5,0,25\n"]
>>> write_lines = [line.replace(" - ", ",") for line in lines]
>>> with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
...     f.writelines(write_lines)
...
```